# VBA Loop through multiple sheets and select next items in dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro gives me copies of tabs and in B2 formula to select next item in drop down list in C3(cell that contain the list/data validation).

When I have a copies of 5 tabs, I want Sheet1 to select first in the list, Sheet 2 to select second and Sheet 3 to select third ....and so on.

Every tab has a static list in cell C3.

Macro that runs copies:

```
Sub Copy_Tabs()Dim x As Integer
x = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy 4075 Wilson")
For numtimes = 1 To x
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson").Copy _
After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson")
Next
End Sub
```

Formula in B2 that return next item in the list:

```
=INDEX(Key!$B$2:$B$57,IF(MATCH(H3,Key!$B$2:$B$57,0)+1>ROW(Key!$B$57)-ROW(Key!$B$2),Key!$B$2,MATCH(H3,Key!$B$2:$B$57,0)+1))
```

Please advised. Thanks!